# What test should I use see if there is a correlation between different populations and percentages of boats found in those locations?

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

I am trying to see if there is a correlation between different location populations (in certain states in India and Bangladesh) and the percentage of boat counts found in each location. For a research project I had to count/locate boats on the Ganges River using GIS and now I need to see if there is any relation between how many boats were found in each location and the population of that location. I'm not very skilled with 'R' and thought it might be best to ask which test would be the best to find out this information.

The table that I have loaded into 'R' is the following data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the percentage of boat counts Poisson distribution would fit. It basically expresses given number of events occuring in a fixed time. In your case it could be number of boats located in a specific place (Ganges River) and time (depending on your interval).
[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) you can find details about the distribution and [here](https://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/probability-distributions/poisson-distribution) you can find simple tutorial how to apply it on R.

For the correlation part it also depends on what you would like to look at. In your case, it seems location population and the percentage of boat and simple linear regression can fit. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20linear%20regression%20is,is%20called%20simple%20linear%20regression.) you can find the theoretical background of it and [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/40-regression-analysis/167-simple-linear-regression-in-r/#:%7E:text=The%20simple%20linear%20regression%20is,function%20of%20the%20x%20variable.) you can find how to apply it on R.